# FirebaseUi - Cast value of UITableViewCell to custom class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebaseui

I can t seem to get the prototypereuseidentifier thing on firebaseUI. If I add a prototypecell, I can only give it a cellidentifier

In my following code, my IBoutlets linked to my custom cell return nil.

here s my code :

```
func loadData() {


    self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: refpost, cellClass: MainWitnessTableViewCell.self, cellReuseIdentifier: "<RIcell>", view: self.tableView)


    self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

        let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot
        print(cell)

        let mycell = cell as! MainWitnessTableViewCell

        let keyy: String = (snap.value.objectForKey("author") as? String)!


        mycell.postContent.text = keyy
        print (mycell.postContent.text)

    }

    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
    }
```

here, mycell.postContent.text returns nil, is there any sorcery that keeps blinding me ? :)
sincerely
Yann

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
cellReuseIdentifier: "<RIcell>"
```

to

```
cellReuseIdentifier: "RIcell"
```

Comment: Hmm can you post your subclass RIcell?

Answer (score 0):

@ jonas : here s the cell class

```
class MainWitnessTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postOwner: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postContent: UITextView!





override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    postContent.text = ""
    postOwner.text = ""

}
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}